# jQuery dropdown hide when mouseover and continue search when back mouseover to textbox

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a jquery dropdown like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".searchs").keyup(function() {
        var searchbox = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'searchword=' + searchbox;
        if (searchbox == '') {
            $("#display").hide();
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "searchs.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Now I want to :

1. Hide dropdown when I mouseover click everywhere.
2. Continue search after I back mouseover to search input box.

Any idea for this case ?

Comment: You should make clear which element is the "dropdown." What the hell is a "mouseover click"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [`focus`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) and [`blur`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) events may come handy for your case.

```
var $display = $("#display");
$(".searchs").on({
  blur: function(){
    $display.hide();
  },
  focus: function(){
    $display.show();
  }
});
```